# Accessing resources in a jar file that are located outside the src folder

Tags: java, jar, resources

I have a project structure where the resources folder is at the same level as src. The resources folder has got a subfolder config, which has a configuration file conffile.ttl. I have included the resources in the classpath while running the program from eclipse.

While reading the conffile.ttl file from my main class, I use

```
URL url =TestPropertyFilePath.class.getClassLoader().getSystemResource("conf/conffile.ttl");
    System.out.println(url.getPath());
```

which works fine. However when I bundle this in a jar and try to run the jar using

```
java -jar testprop.jar TestPropertyFilePath
```

Java cannot find the conffile.ttl file. I would like advice on how to access the conffile.ttl from within the jar.

Comment: Try [TestPropertyFilePath.class.getRescource("/...")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) instead

Comment: Is the ttl file in the jar file?

Comment: Yes. When I did the bundling, I included the resources folder. So the jar file has the packages for the classes and the resources at the same level

Comment: @madprogrammer your suggestion worked. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 TestPropertyFilePath.class.getClassLoader().getSystemResource("conf.conffile");
```